# Filtering and loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am building this gallery page http://www.zivaexotika.cz/galleries_masonry_wall.php
And as you can see I have filter on right side of menu nav. But.. I have two problems with whole gallery. Filter works only with loaded photos. So if you are not srolling for load more photos, filtr can't get all photos from one data-id. How can I customize it? Next problem is in loading. If I would have 500 photos for example and visitor will see first 15, after scroll action it will start to load all 485 photos. That's very slow and bad solution.

This is Data_manager.php

```
<?php

class DataManager
{
/**
 * @param $request - typ požadavku $_GET, $_POST
 * @param $connectionInfo - informace pro připojení do DB
 * @param $sqlQuery - SQL dotaz, který má být proveden
 * @param $params - paramtery pro dotaz, $query->bindParam(:xx, $xx);
 * @return vrátí výpis dat
 */

static function updateHashtag($id, $data) {

    if($id && $data) {

        if(strtolower($data) === 'null') {
            $data = null;
        }

        $dbh = self::db();

        try {
            $query = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE `photos` SET `hashtags` = :hashtags WHERE id = :id');
            $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindParam(':hashtags', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();

            // Vratime jmeno fotky (ID)
            return true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

static function removePhoto($id, $ext) {

    if($id && $ext) {
        $dbh = self::db();

        try {
            $query = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM `photos` WHERE `id` = :id');
            $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();

            if($query) {
                if(!unlink('../../images/gallery/' . $id . '.' . $ext)) {
                    return 'Hlavní fotka nemohla být smazána.. ERROR';
                }
                if(!unlink('../../images/gallery/thumbs/' . $id . '.' . $ext)) {
                    return 'Miniatura fotky nemohla být smazána.. ERROR';
                }
                return 'Fotka byla úspěšně vymazána!';
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            return $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

static function insertPhoto($ext)
{

    if (!empty($ext)) {
        $dbh = self::db();

        try {
            $query = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `photos` VALUES (NULL, :ext, NULL)');
            $query->bindParam(':ext', $ext, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();

            // Vratime jmeno fotky (ID)
            return self::lastInsertID();
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

static function lastInsertID()
{
    $dbh = self::db();

    try {
        return $dbh->query('SELECT id FROM `photos` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        return $ex->getMessage();
    }
}


static function getPhotos($fotekDefault = 10)
{
    $dbh = self::db();

    $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, ' . $fotekDefault;
    $data = self::sql_exec($dbh, $sqlQuery);

    return $data;
}

static function getLastDownloadedID($fotekDefault = 10) {
    $dbh = self::db();

    $query = 'SELECT id FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, ' . $fotekDefault;
    $data = self::sql_exec($dbh, $query);

    $id = null;

    foreach ($data as $dato) {
        if($id === null)
            $id = $dato['id'];

        if ($id > $dato['id']) {
            $id = $dato['id'];
        }
    }

    return $id;
}

/**
 * @param $connectionInfo - informace pro připojení do DB
 * @param $sqlQuery - SQL dotaz, který má být proveden
 * @param $params - paramtery pro dotaz, $query->bindParam(:xx, $xx);
 * @return vrátí výpis dat
 */

static function getPhotosJson($fotekDefault = 10)
{

    $dbh = self::db();


    $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id < ' . self::getLastDownloadedID($fotekDefault) . ' ORDER BY id DESC';

    $fotky = self::sql_exec($dbh, $sqlQuery);

    if(!empty($fotky)) {
        $hashtags = $fotka['hashtags'];
        // Definice pro pozdejsi pouziti
        $poleFoto = [
            "items" => ""
        ];

        foreach ($fotky as $fotka) {
            $poleFoto["items"][] = [
                "imageSrc" => "../../images/gallery/thumbs/" . $fotka['id'] . "." . $fotka['extension'],
                "lightBoxImage" => "../../images/gallery/" . $fotka['id'] . "." . $fotka['extension'],
                "layoutType" => intval(6),
                "category" => $fotka['hashtags'],
                "galleryName" => "gallery_wall",
                "iconType" => "photo",
                "statLink1" => array(
                    "amount" => 15,
                    "icon" => "eye"
                ),
                "statLink2" => array(
                    "amount" => 100,
                    "icon" => "heart-empty"
                )
            ];
        }

        return $poleFoto;
    }

    return 'nic';
}
```

Next file is index.php

```
<?php
 /**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Tomas2D
 * Date: 18.11.15
 * Time: 12:26
 */

const
fotekDefault = 30;


require 'DataManager.php';

/**
  * @return bool
 */
function isAjax() {
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // Jedná se o AJAX
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

function getDefaultPhotos()
{
$fotky = DataManager::getPhotos(fotekDefault);

if(!empty($fotky)) {
    //var_dump($fotky);
    foreach($fotky as $fotka)
    {
        $hashtags = $fotka['hashtags'];
        ?>

        <div class="isotope_item <?= $hashtags ?>">

            <div class="wall_j_item type_1">
                <a href="../../images/gallery/<?= $fotka['id'] ?>.<?= $fotka['extension'] ?>"
                   class="fancybox wall_image photo" data-rel="gallery_wall" rel="gallery_wall">
                    <img class="item_image"
                         src="../../images/gallery/thumbs/<?= $fotka['id'] ?>.<?= $fotka['extension'] ?>">
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php
    }
}
}

function getJsonPhotos()
{
echo json_encode(DataManager::getPhotosJson(fotekDefault), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}

/* Aplikační logika */
if(isAjax()) {
getJsonPhotos();
} else {
getDefaultPhotos();
}
```

And main file for user interface is this:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<head>

    <!-- Basic page needs
    ============================================ -->
    <title>Jaccobphoto | Portfolio</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

    <!-- Mobile specific metas
    ============================================ -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Favicon
    ============================================ -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/fav_icon.ico">

    <!-- Google web fonts
    ============================================ -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900,200italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Libs CSS
    ============================================ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/portfolio/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Theme CSS
    ============================================ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/portfolio/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css"
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/rtl.css"> -->

    <!-- JS Libs
    ============================================ -->
    <script src="plugins/modernizr.js"></script>

    <!-- Old IE stylesheet
    ============================================ -->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/oldie.css">
        <script src="js/placeholderIE.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body class="horizontal_menu_type" style="owerflow: hidden">

    <div id="page_loader" class="page_loader">
        <div id="loader"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Cookie Control & Old ie Message - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

    <div class="messages_wrap">

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Old IE Message - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>

        <div class="old_ie_message">

            <div class="on_the_sides">

                <div class="left_side">

                    <i class="icon-attention"></i> <b>Attention!</b> This page may not display correctly. You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer. For a faster, safer browsing experience.

                </div>

                <div class="right_side">

                    <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode" class="btn small transparent black" target="_blank">Update Now!</a>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <![endif]-->

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of Old IE Message - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

    </div>

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of Cookie Control & Old ie Message - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

    <div id="document_wrap">

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Header - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <header role="banner" id="header" class="hm">

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Logo - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

            <a href="index.html" class="logo" style="width:200px; margin:15px;">

                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">

            </a>

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End Logo - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Horizontal Main Navigation - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

            <div id="horizontal_menu_wrap" class="hm_wrap">

                <nav>

                    <ul class="navigation">

                        <li>

                            <a href="index.html">Domů</a>

                        </li>

                        <li>

                            <a href="prodejci.html">Pro prodejce</a>

                        </li>



                    </ul>

                </nav>

            </div>

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of Main Navigation Container - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Top Buttons - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

            <div id="top_actions_wrap">

                <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Isotope Filter - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

                <p style="
display: inline-block;
align: left;
text-align: left;
margin: 5px;
">FILTR</p>

                <div id="filter_wrap">

                    <span id="filter_btn" class="si-icon toggle_box" data-width="28" data-height="28" data-event="click" data-icon-name="filter"></span>


                    <ul id="filter" class="animation_box">

                        <li data-filter="*">Vše</li>
                        <li data-filter=".jesteri">Ještěři</li>
                        <li data-filter=".savci">Savci</li>
                        <li data-filter=".krmivo">Krmiva</li>
                        <li data-filter=".hadi">Hadi</li>
                        <li data-filter=".bezobratli">Bezobratlí</li>


                    </ul>

                </div>

                <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of Isotope Filter - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->


                <span id="toggle_menu" class="si-icon toggle_menu2" data-width="36" data-height="36" data-event="click" data-icon-name="hamburgerCross"></span>

            </div><!--/ #top_btns_wrap -->

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of Top Buttons - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        </header>

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End Header - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Page content - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <div id="page_wrap" class="wall">

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Isotope Container - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Isotope Container - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

            <div class="gallery_isotope_container full_width" data-max-request-posts="20" data-page-type="gallery" data-masonry="true" data-url="php/class/index.php">

                <?php

                include 'php/class/index.php';

                ?>

            </div>

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of Isotope Container - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of Isotope Container - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        </div><!--/ .page_wrapper -->

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End page content - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Footer - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <footer role="contentinfo" id="footer" class="fullscreen">

            <span class="copyright">&copy; 2015 Jakub Čuřík. Všechna práva vyhrazena.</span>

            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Social icons - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->



            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End Social icons - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        </footer>

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End Footer - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

    </div>

    <!-- Include Libs & Plugins
    ============================================ -->
    <script src="js/portfolio/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/portfolio/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <script src="plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/svg/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/svg/svgicons-config.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/svg/svgicons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53b561d45194bf47" async="async"></script>
    <script src="plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"><=/script>
    <script src="plugins/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>

    <!-- Theme files
    ============================================ -->

    <script src="js/portfolio/js/theme.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/portfolio/js/theme.plugins.js"></script>

</body>
```

Thank you very much!
And sorry for my english